Check if number is within a range
I have a total amount and then I have an amount that a user can insert.
I want to check whether the amount that the user inserts is within 0.2 of the total amount.
eg. Total amount is 58.79 and the user inserts 58.78 or 58.80, if this is the case then I want to console out "Allowed" else if not the case then "Not allowed".
another eg. Total amount is 60 and the user inserts 59.99 or 60.01, if this is the case then I want to console out "Allowed" else if not the case then "Not allowed".
How can I go about this?
My attempt
  const Range = totalAmount - userInsertedAmount;
  if ( (Range < 0.2) || (Range > 0.2)) {
    console.log('valid');
  } else {
    console.log('invalid');
  }

One last thing, is there a way to do it without using any built in Javascript methods like abs etc.

Math.abs(totalAmount - userInsertedAmount) < 0.02 - note ... 0.02 - note 2: your code is true for every value except if totalAmount is exactly 0.2 greater than userInsertedAmount

0.2 is not 2 decimal places it is only one. Also, what value of Rnage will these be false for Range < 0.2) || (Range > 0.2

Really we can think about
valid=(this.range>=-.02 && this.range<=.02)

But, e.g.:
  totalAmount=58.79
  userInsertedAmount=58.81
  range=(totalAmount - userInsertedAmount);
  valid=(range>=-.02 && range<=.02)

  range becomes `-0.020000000000003126` and the condition is false

So we can do, see the "hack" +(number.toFixed(2)), toFixed becomes 2 decimals, and the "+" convert To number
  totalAmount=58.79
  userInsertedAmount=58.81
  range=+(totalAmount - userInsertedAmount).toFixed(2);
  valid=(range>=-.02 && range<=.02)

  range becomes -0.02 and the condition is true


This works only because 0.02 is read as 0.0200000000000000004  (a number >0.02, test with ((0.02).toPrecision(18)). 0.03 is read as 0.0299999999999999989, a number <0.03.
